# Dynamic Nodes and relationship creation in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am storing Hierarchy data in Neo4j. I want to store history of the Node. Consider I have a label called GROUP and the earlier name was "MARKETING" now it has been changed to "MARKET123". So i want to create a new node where the name will be MARKET123 and the create a relationship with other connected node same as for the older node named "MARKETING"...
  But all this i want to do dynamically instead of passing the other Nodes name and the relationship value in the cypher query.

Please suggest me how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can add versioning to your graph nodes.

Here is a graph gist about time-based versioning that you may adapt to your needs.

http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?608bf0701e3306a23e77